# Populate URL parameter into h:inputText

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets

I am using the following code to retrieve URL params into a JavaScript variable.

```
function getUrlParams() {
  var params = {};
  window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(str,key,value) {
    params[key] = value;
  });
  return params;
}
var vName = getUrlParams()["vName"];
```

I have to set `vName` into `h:inputText`.

`document.getElementById("Forid:Fldid").value = vName; // didn't work`

I am working on Facelets.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My concern is, I am unable to set the variable into the textfield (h:inputtext).

Comment: What is id of your element to which you want to set this value?

Comment: Why don't you just use `<f:viewParam>`?

Comment: document.getElementById("Forid:Fldid").value= vName. formid:inputtextid. It is the inputtextid. A similar program using html and javascript is working fine. But we have xhtml

Comment: @ BalusC I haven't tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it the hard way. Use [`<f:viewParam>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html).

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="vName" value="#{bean.vName}" />
</f:metadata>
...
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.vName}" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private String vName;

    // Getter+setter.
}
```

That's all.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)